# Importing HTML into template

Tags: html, ajax, json, dom

I'm getting a html snippet from json that I'm bringing into my template, but it is rendering in the browser with the element tags like this:

```
<p>From my latest family trip to the Grand Bazaar in Istanbul, Turkey.</p>
```

How do I get it to read the output not as a string but as html?

Comment: +1 to offset random downvote.

Comment: What type of content JSON has? can you show the structure of JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter or the [`autoescape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) tag.

Comment: THe safe filter worked, but not the autoescape didn't.  Thanks!